# Colorir estados específico em um mapa?

Tags: r

Fiz um mapa simples e queria colorir alguns estados específicos (ex: Maranhão, Rio de Janeiro) e deixar os demais branco. Alguém saberia dizer como eu posso fazer isso? Cheguei até aqui.
Outra pergunta é, alguém sabe botar as siglas dos estados?

```
install.packages("geobr")
library(geobr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
datasets <- list_geobr()
states <- read_state(
  year=2019, 
  showProgress = FALSE
)
no_axis <- theme(axis.title=element_blank(), axis.text=element_blank(), axis.ticks=element_blank())
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=States, color="#FEBF57", size=.15, show.legend = FALSE) +
  labs(subtitle="States", size=8) +
  theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode criar uma variável para identificar os Estados que deseja. Não uso o pacote `geobr`, usei de exemplo o shapefile baixado do IBGE, o resultado será o mesmo:

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

ufs <- read_sf('~/Shapefiles/IBGE/BR_UF_2021.shp')

str(ufs)
#> sf [27 × 5] (S3: sf/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#>  $ CD_UF    : chr [1:27] "11" "12" "13" "14" ...
#>  $ NM_UF    : chr [1:27] "Rondônia" "Acre" "Amazonas" "Roraima" ...
#>  $ SIGLA    : chr [1:27] "RO" "AC" "AM" "RR" ...
#>  $ NM_REGIAO: chr [1:27] "Norte" "Norte" "Norte" "Norte" ...
#>  $ geometry :sfc_MULTIPOLYGON of length 27; first list element: List of 1
#>   ..$ :List of 1
#>   .. ..$ : num [1:8812, 1:2] -62.9 -62.9 -62.9 -62.8 -62.8 ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "XY" "MULTIPOLYGON" "sfg"
#>  - attr(*, "sf_column")= chr "geometry"
#>  - attr(*, "agr")= Factor w/ 3 levels "constant","aggregate",..: NA NA NA NA
#>   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "CD_UF" "NM_UF" "SIGLA" "NM_REGIAO"

ggplot(ufs, aes(fill = NM_UF %in% c('Maranhão', 'Rio de Janeiro'))) +
  geom_sf() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('gray', 'blue'), guide = FALSE) +
  theme_void()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(geobr)
```

Baixando o shps:

```
estados_br <- read_state()
```

Uma possibilidade é vc filtrar os estados de interesse com a função `dplyr::filter()`:

```
ma_rj <- estados_br %>% 
  filter(abbrev_state %in% c("MA", "RJ"))
```

E depois plotar ambos, colorindo o mapa de todos os estados de branco e o dos estados selecionados de vermelhor (por exemplo):

Para colocar as siglas dos estados, vc pode usar a função `geom_sf_text()` ou `geom_sf_label()`.

```
ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data = estados_br, fill = "white")+
  geom_sf(data = ma_rj, fill = "red")+
  geom_sf_text(data = ma_rj, aes(label = abbrev_state))+
  theme_minimal()
```